# Tikz: Division and Addition for Node Names

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a graph that is essentially just a long line with a triangle at one end and a square at the other end.  I need there to be a chain of length 26 between the triangle and the square.  When I tried with the code below, I got the error "Missing Number, treated as 0".  Other attempts have told me that there are no nodes named "P0+1". How do I do division, addition, etc. on node names to iterate through them as I'd like?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}{
    \node (P\x) at (-\x/2,0){};
    }
    \foreach \x in {13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}{
    \node (P\x) at ({\x-13}/2,0){};
    }

    \node (P27) at (14,1){};
    \node (P28) at (14,-1){};
    \node (P29) at (-14,1){};
    \node (P30) at (-14,-1){};
    \node (P31) at (-15,0){};


    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31}{
    \fill (P\x) circle (2pt);
    }

    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}{
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P\x)--(P\x+1);
    }

    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P26)--(P27);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P27)--(P28);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P28) -- (P26);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P13)--(P29);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P29)--(P30);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P30) -- (P31);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P31) -- (P13);


    \draw (0,-3) node[below]{Figure 3.4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You are referring to the nodes _named_ `P1+1`, `P2+1`, and so on (_not_ `P2`, `P3`, etc). Try using `\foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1);}] in` and then using the coordinates `(P\x) -- (P\y)`.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain places where TikZ don't parse the math such as node names and a few other places. Inside a loop you can instead use the `evaluate=<var> as <resulting var> using <formula>` syntax. You could have used a counter that starts from 1 in this specific case too.

Moreover you need to use `(...)` to nest the math and `{...}` to hide it from the parser. Hence the code becomes

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}{
    \node (P\x) at (-\x/2,0){};
    }
    \foreach \x in {13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}{
    \node (P\x) at ({(\x-13)/2)},0){};
    }

    \node (P27) at (14,1){};
    \node (P28) at (14,-1){};
    \node (P29) at (-14,1){};
    \node (P30) at (-14,-1){};
    \node (P31) at (-15,0){};


    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31}{
    \fill (P\x) circle (2pt);
    }

    \foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \evalx using int(\x+1)] in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}{
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P\x)--(P\evalx);
    }

    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P26)--(P27);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P27)--(P28);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P28) -- (P26);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P13)--(P29);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P29)--(P30);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P30) -- (P31);
    \draw[line width=1 pt] (P31) -- (P13);


    \draw (0,-3) node[below]{Figure 3.4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use multiple variables in the formula?